# What could make replica disappear?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-collector

I have a few services added as layers in a map, that is configured to be used in ArcGIS Collector(20.2.1), and I am facing an issue with the synchronization of my edits.
I checked the REST end of the service and found that the replicas are no more available and have disappeared.

I have isolated one of the sync errors with a couple of services and it seems that the corresponding replicas have disappeared from the list of registered replicas:

```
{"error":{" code":404, "message": "Unable to synchronize replica.", "details":["Replica with GUID: 0cc27ea0-0391-455f-8432-70e3fca794c9 does not exist on the server."]}}
```

What could be the reason for the disappeared replica?

Comment: Did anyone update the service at all like an overwrite to add new fields that were initially added to the local data in Pro/ArcMap.

Comment: Hello @RussRoberts, the services were not updated at all.